# Bug in some Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

I have a survey that is displayed via an xsl stylesheet. I have a section that checks to see if the user selects "Neither" for several options, if so display an additional question.

Here is the JQuery:

```
function block3Check(){
    var neither23 = $('input[name=response23]:checked', '#editForm').val();
    var neither24 = $('input[name=response24]:checked', '#editForm').val();
    var neither25 = $('input[name=response25]:checked', '#editForm').val();
    var neither26 = $('input[name=response26]:checked', '#editForm').val();

    if(neither23 && neither24 && neither25 && neither26 == 'Neither')
    {

        $('#question-27').slideDown(500);
        $('#after-link').hide();
    }
}
```

I receive no errors or warning on this code, however I think the bug is in my IF statement, or my XSL code. The new question is supposed to slide down if all are selected as neither, however currently does so if 3 of the 4 are selected.

XSL:

```
<xsl:when test="../@id='23'">
    <div class="block3Glory hidden">
        <hr /><p><br /></p>
        <div id="question-23">
            <strong>Suppose you were considering <u>only the following two</u> study abroad programs. Which, if either, would you be more likely to choose?<br /></strong>
            <p></p>
            <table><tr><td><img src="survey/study_abroad/b3q1-programA.jpg" /></td><td><input name="response23" value="Program-A" type="radio" />Program A</td></tr></table>
            <table><tr><td><img src="survey/study_abroad/b3q1-programB.jpg" /></td><td><input name="response23" value="Program-B" type="radio" />Program B</td></tr></table>
            <table style="padding-top: 8px;"><tr><td style="border-top: 1px solid #000; width: 600px; text-align: center;"><b>I would choose neither</b></td><td style="padding-left: 10px;"><input name="response23" value="Neither" type="radio" onclick="block3Check()"/>Neither<br /></td></tr></table>
            <p><br /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="../@id='24'">
    <div class="block3Glory hidden">
        <hr /><p><br /></p>
        <div id="question-24">
            <strong>Now suppose <u>instead</u> that you were considering <u>only the following two</u> study abroad programs. Which, if either, would you be more likely to choose?<br /></strong>
            <p></p>
            <table><tr><td><img src="survey/study_abroad/b3q2-programA.jpg" /></td><td><input name="response24" value="Program-A" type="radio" />Program A</td></tr></table>
            <table><tr><td><img src="survey/study_abroad/b3q2-programB.jpg" /></td><td><input name="response24" value="Program-B" type="radio" />Program B</td></tr></table>
            <table style="padding-top: 8px;"><tr><td style="border-top: 1px solid #000; width: 600px; text-align: center;"><b>I would choose neither</b></td><td style="padding-left: 10px;"><input name="response24" value="Neither" type="radio" onclick="block3Check()"/>Neither<br /></td></tr></table>
            <p><br /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="../@id='25'">
    <div class="block3Glory hidden">
    <hr /><p><br /></p>
        <div id="question-25">
            <strong>Now suppose <u>instead</u> that you were considering <u>only the following two</u> study abroad programs. Which, if either, would you be more likely to choose?<br /></strong>
            <p></p>
            <table><tr><td><img src="survey/study_abroad/b3q3-programA.jpg" /></td><td><input name="response25" value="Program-A" type="radio" />Program A</td></tr></table>
            <table><tr><td><img src="survey/study_abroad/b3q3-programB.jpg" /></td><td><input name="response25" value="Program-B" type="radio" />Program B</td></tr></table>
            <table style="padding-top: 8px;"><tr><td style="border-top: 1px solid #000; width: 600px; text-align: center;"><b>I would choose neither</b></td><td style="padding-left: 10px;"><input name="response25" value="Neither" type="radio" onclick="block3Check()"/>Neither<br /></td></tr></table>
            <p><br /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="../@id='26'">
    <div class="block3Glory hidden">
    <hr /><p><br /></p>
        <div id="question-26">
            <strong>Now suppose <u>instead</u> that you were considering <u>only the following two</u> study abroad programs. Which, if either, would you be more likely to choose?<br /></strong>
            <p></p>
            <table><tr><td><img src="survey/study_abroad/b3q4-programA.jpg" /></td><td><input name="response26" value="Program-A" type="radio" />Program A</td></tr></table>
            <table><tr><td><img src="survey/study_abroad/b3q4-programB.jpg" /></td><td><input name="response26" value="Program-B" type="radio" />Program B</td></tr></table>
            <table style="padding-top: 8px;"><tr><td style="border-top: 1px solid #000; width: 600px; text-align: center;"><b>I would choose neither</b></td><td style="padding-left: 10px;"><input name="response26" value="Neither" type="radio" onclick="block3Check()"/>Neither<br /></td></tr></table>
            <p><br /><a id="after-link" href="javascript:" onclick="showAfterBlock()">Continue</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:when>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I approved the && edit, but in XSLT those have to be &amp; unless they are defined. Which in this case they were not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-statement is always false. You should check the 'Neither' value for all variables, like so:

```
 if(neither23 == 'Neither' && neither24 == 'Neither' && neither25 == 'Neither' && neither26 == 'Neither') {
     $('#question-27').slideDown(500);
     $('#after-link').hide();
 }
```

Comment: This was it. Thank you very much Victor!

Answer (score 1):

`if(neither23 && neither24 && neither25 && neither26 == 'Neither')` 
If you want to check for all to be equal to `Neither`, then that's just wrong.

You could use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/Array/every) (with polyfill to support older browsers):

```
if([neither23,neither24,neither25,neither26].every(function(elm){ return elm === 'Neither';})) {
  $('#question-27').slideDown(500);
  $('#after-link').hide();
}
```